# Intervention image aspect ratio

Tags: image, image-processing, laravel-4

I want to resize my images through Intervention image functionality in Laravel 4, but to keep aspect ratio of an image, this is what my code looks like:

```
$image_make         = Image::make($main_picture->getRealPath())->fit('245', '245', function($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); })->save('images/articles/'.$gender.'/thumbnails/245x245/'.$picture_name);
```

Problem is that this doesn't keep aspect ratio of my image, thanks.

Comment: `fit()` should keep the ratio automatically. So no need for the constraint. I suggest you also pass the height and width as numbers and not strings. Otherwise I see nothing wrong here...

Comment: @lukasgeiter I meant resize() doesn't keep aspect ratio (sorry), fit() keeps aspect ratio but it cuts parts of an image that are important to me...

Comment: So what exactly is your expected result? if the ratio doesn't match the target ratio?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Well fit() does resize the image by my expectations (245x245), but it also cuts some parts of the image, I want to resize it without cutting some parts...

Comment: And what should happen in the areas where there is "no image" transparent? black background?

Comment: @lukasgeiter This is what fit() does: http://pokit.org/get/img/aa89d980841a0e7271ec56eb616496eb.jpg

This is the original image: http://pokit.org/get/img/5734ce45cd8fa8b94dbb3453a0b64822.jpg

Comment: I know what fit does, but I need to know what you want... well here comes another guess: do you want the result to be 245px on the longer side (either height or width)?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I want width and height to be 245px, so my image would be 245px wide and 245px high with all of its parts without cutting them...

Comment: And the rest of those 245x245px that is not covered by the image? should it be transparent (png) or a color?

Answer (score 35):

If you need to resize within constraints you should use `resize` not `fit`. If you also need center the image inside the constraints, you should create a new `canvas` and insert the resized image within that:

```
// This will generate an image with transparent background
// If you need to have a background you can pass a third parameter (e.g: '#000000')
$canvas = Image::canvas(245, 245);

$image  = Image::make($main_picture->getRealPath())->resize(245, 245, function($constraint)
{
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$canvas->insert($image, 'center');
$canvas->save('images/articles/'.$gender.'/thumbnails/245x245/'.$picture_name);
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. This is exactly what I needed to keep all my thumbnails consistent in size. Thank you!

Comment: How would you make this for regular images ?
When user uploaded several types of images like nature,animal,human etc. , because there is no fixed background color, that is multiple background color exist on those images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions:

    According to your code, when you fixed the image width, the image will resize by a ratio, that will make the image height. May be it is undefined to find the height from the width of an image. How to fixed this problem.

2. If I resize the image using laravel intervention package using a width and height, the image looks a bad shape of original image. How can I fixed this.

Answer (score 12):

Just resize it to max width/height of the image, and the make the canvas fit the max width & height desired

```
Image::make($main_picture->getRealPath())->resize(245, 245,
    function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })
->resizeCanvas(245, 245)
->save('images/articles/'.$gender.'/thumbnails/245x245/'.$picture_name, 80);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread but I'm sharing my implementation if someone will need it someday.

My implementation is looking at the received image's aspect ratio and will resize (if required) with the new height or width.

```
public function resizeImage($image, $requiredSize) {
    $width = $image->width();
    $height = $image->height();

    // Check if image resize is required or not
    if ($requiredSize >= $width && $requiredSize >= $height) return $image;

    $newWidth;
    $newHeight;

    $aspectRatio = $width/$height;
    if ($aspectRatio >= 1.0) {
        $newWidth = $requiredSize;
        $newHeight = $requiredSize / $aspectRatio;
    } else {
        $newWidth = $requiredSize * $aspectRatio;
        $newHeight = $requiredSize;
    }


    $image->resize($newWidth, $newHeight);
    return $image;
}
```

You need to pass an image (`$image = Image::make($fileImage->getRealPath());`) and a required size (e.g: `480`).

Here are the outputs

1. Uploaded image: `100x100`. Nothing gonna happen, because the width
   and the height are less than the required `480` size.
2. Uploaded image: `3000x1200`. This is a landscape image and will be resized to: `480x192` (keeping the aspect ratio)
3. Uploaded image: `980x2300`. This is a portrait image and will be resized to: `204x480`.
4. Uploaded image: `1000x1000`. This is 1:1 aspect ratio image having both width and height equal. This will be resized to: `480x480`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `null` in width or height ;

```
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); });
```

or

```
$img->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); });
```